# Short Story - Underground Dystopian possibly Steampunk

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, steampunk

I remember reading a story about possibly a boy and girl living in an underground city because of some event that sent the population underground - it was a short story, I believe, possibly in SF/F, or Asimov's, or Weird Tales, and it had the same overtones as "This Time of Darkness" by Helen Hoover and "Dark Universe" by Daniel Galouye, but I'm certain it was a short story, not a novel.  I don't believe it was associated with a war or nuclear accident, but I could have forgotten that part.  I remember it really had a steampunk flavor.  Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: The first thing I thought of for underground city + steampunk + boy and girl was City of Ember, but obviously that's too recent. I think there are quite a lot of stories that involve underground cities. Any other details you can provide about events in the story? How old the story is?

Comment: It would have have to been in the last 5 to 7 years, but then again... it might have appeared in Weird Tales' Steampunk issue... I'll check that if I can find it...

Comment: It would have have to been in the last 5 to 7 years, but then again... it might have appeared in Weird Tales' Steampunk issue... I'll check that if I can find it... found it, was thinking it might be J.M. McDermott's Labyrinth piece, but no... I remember it had a boy and girl in it, they were struggling for something, pipes, wires, I don't know, but in the end they broke through to the surface (earth) and into the sun...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly Hugh Howey's [*Wool*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005FC52L0)  series, which started with a short story published in 2011.

From the [*Wiki*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silo_%28series%29) entry:

> The story of Wool takes place on a post-apocalyptic Earth. Humanity
>   clings to survival in the Silo, a subterranean city extending over one
>   hundred and fifty stories beneath the surface. The series initially
>   follows the character of Holston, the sheriff of the Silo, with
>   subsequent volumes focusing on the characters of Juliette, Jahns, and
>   Marnes. An ongoing storyline of the series is the focus on the mystery
>   behind the Silo and the secrets it holds. The Silo's mystery is
>   eventually revealed by the end of book five; books six through eight
>   comprise a prequel to the series. Book nine pulls the storylines
>   together.

Comment: I don't remember a sheriff...if I remember correctly, it read more like The City of Ember by Jeanne Duprau, but I', certain it was a short story...